# TORTOISE: Dev Server, Production Server and Final client

Tags: git, svn, architecture, tortoisesvn, development-environment

I have two servers.
One is for developing and testing applications
The other is to release the software to production (We are a textile factory)

Right now, we finish the development and put the "final version" to the production server (drag and drop)

As you can imagine, this takes lots of times when we make an upgrade to the software. We need to drag and drop again, and sometimes the projects are big

So, I am looking for a solution that allows you to make a Commit at the developing server and then we can Upgrade the software at the production server.

Can I do that with SVN Tortoise?

Or maybe using Git?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking about... Could please elaborate your complete question?

Comment: @royalTS I am sorry for the explanation. Hope its better now and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm having some trouble parsing what you are asking, but let me give it a go:

You are looking to have something automatically build and deploy the production server when and if it is verified on the development server.  This is not really a function of your version control software (SVN vs Git), but more the responsibility of your build process.  Modern companies solve this with [Continuous Integration (CI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) and [Continuous Delivery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery) (CD) processes.

This is best handled through a CI/CD tool like Jenkins, although your ultimate solution strongly depends on what technical stack you are using (.NET? C++? Java?).

Comment: We are using PHP

So, we first develop an application in a Server A
In that same server we test. When the application is ready we copy and paste the application to Server B

So, imagine that two months later the client needs some change in the app. 

I will do the changes in Server A. But I only change two or three files. Is there a way that automatically I can send only the files I changed to Server B and not the entire project?

Comment: You could let the version control do the heavy lifting.  It would have the added benefit of allowing you to roll back fairly quickly.  So, check the code out on the dev server... update it there and push it back to the SVN or Git server.. when you are done, check it out on the prod server.

Comment: I would highly recommend you create a "Prod" branch so that merges are intentional.